# Sharing wwwroot folder cause 401.3 error in IIS

Tags: iis

when I share my project folder inside `wwwroot` folder, I get 401.3 error.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sololution:
In IIS manager/Authenication -> Anonymous Authenication, the default website user is ISUR,
you change it to use application pool identity